# How can I use zip()

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

x = (173, 175, 162.5, 178) 
y = (166, 164, 154, 169)

w = 0.90
b = 8.00

for x_i, y_i in zip(x, y):
  y_hat = x_i * w + b 
  err = y_i - y_hat
  w_rate = x_i
  w_grad = w + w_rate * err
  b_grad = b + 1 * err

print(y_hat)
print(w_rate)
print(err)
print(w_grad, b_grad)
```

I used a zip function, but this code only outputs an expression for the last value. I want to calculate the whole using the zip function and find the best w_grad, b_grad. What should I do?

Comment: Is using zip a requirement or would you be interested in a vectorised solution?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you iterate through the for loop, b_grad and w_grad are always updated so you only get the last calculated value. You don't define what a 'best' value would be for w_grad and b_grad is but I will assume the BEST value will be the highest one. To find the highest w_grad value, one method is to have a separate variable that only updates if the newly calculated w_grad is 'better' the the current best one.

```
import numpy as np

x = (173, 175, 162.5, 178) 
y = (166, 164, 154, 169)

w = 0.90
b = 8.00
// assumes w_grad is always greater than 0
best_w_grad = 0    

for x_i, y_i in zip(x, y):
  y_hat = x_i * w + b 
  err = y_i - y_hat
  w_rate = x_i
  w_grad = w + w_rate * err
  b_grad = b + 1 * err

  // set the new best value
  if w_grad > best_w_grad: best_w_grad = w_grad

print(y_hat)
print(w_rate)
print(err)
print(best_w_grad, b_grad)
```